# Cisco VPN Client dropping connection

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, dmz, cisco-pix

Using Windows XP and Cisco VPN client version 5.0.4.xxx to connect to a remote customer site.  We are able to establish the connection and start an RDP session, but within 1-2 minutes the connection drops and the VPN connection disconnects.  The PC making the connection is on a DMZ which is NATed to a public IP address.

If we move the PC directly onto the internet without being on the DMZ the connection works and we don't encounter any disconnects.  We use a PIX 515E running 7.2.4 and don't have any problems with similar setups connecting to other customer sites from the DMZ.

The VPN setup on the client side is pretty basic, using IPSec over TCP port 10000.  Not sure what device they are using on the peer, but my guess would be an ASA.

Any idea as to what the problem would be?  Below is the logs from the VPN client when the problem occurs.  The real IP address has been changed to: RemotePeerIP.

4      14:39:30.593  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   CM/0x63100024
Attempt connection with server "RemotePeerIP"

5      14:39:30.593  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   CM/0x6310002F
Allocated local TCP port 1942 for TCP connection.

6      14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IPSEC/0x63700008
IPSec driver successfully started

7      14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IPSEC/0x63700014
Deleted all keys

8      14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   IPSEC/0x6370002C
Sent 256 packets, 0 were fragmented.

9      14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   IPSEC/0x63700020
TCP SYN sent to RemotePeerIP, src port 1942, dst port 10000

10     14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   IPSEC/0x6370001C
TCP SYN-ACK received from RemotePeerIP, src port 10000, dst port 1942

11     14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   IPSEC/0x63700021
TCP ACK sent to RemotePeerIP, src port 1942, dst port 10000

12     14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Warning/3    IPSEC/0xA370001C
Bad cTCP trailer, Rsvd 26984, Magic# 63697672h, trailer len 101, MajorVer 13, MinorVer 10

13     14:39:30.796  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   CM/0x63100029
TCP connection established on port 10000 with server "RemotePeerIP"

14     14:39:31.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   CM/0x63100024
Attempt connection with server "RemotePeerIP"

15     14:39:31.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   IKE/0x6300003B
Attempting to establish a connection with RemotePeerIP.

16     14:39:31.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000013
SENDING >>> ISAKMP OAK AG (SA, KE, NON, ID, VID(Xauth), VID(dpd), VID(Frag), VID(Unity)) to RemotePeerIP

17     14:39:36.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000021
Retransmitting last packet!

18     14:39:36.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000013
SENDING >>> ISAKMP OAK AG (Retransmission) to RemotePeerIP

19     14:39:41.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000021
Retransmitting last packet!

20     14:39:41.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000013
SENDING >>> ISAKMP OAK AG (Retransmission) to RemotePeerIP

21     14:39:46.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000021
Retransmitting last packet!

22     14:39:46.296  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000013
SENDING >>> ISAKMP OAK AG (Retransmission) to RemotePeerIP

23     14:39:51.328  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000017
Marking IKE SA for deletion  (I_Cookie=AEFC3FFF0405BBD6 R_Cookie=0000000000000000) reason = DEL_REASON_PEER_NOT_RESPONDING

24     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x6300004B
Discarding IKE SA negotiation (I_Cookie=AEFC3FFF0405BBD6 R_Cookie=0000000000000000) reason = DEL_REASON_PEER_NOT_RESPONDING

25     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   CM/0x63100014
Unable to establish Phase 1 SA with server "RemotePeerIP" because of "DEL_REASON_PEER_NOT_RESPONDING"

26     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/5   CM/0x63100025
Initializing CVPNDrv

27     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   CM/0x6310002D
Resetting TCP connection on port 10000

28     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   CM/0x63100030
Removed local TCP port 1942 for TCP connection.

29     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   CM/0x63100046
Set tunnel established flag in registry to 0.

30     14:39:51.828  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IKE/0x63000001
IKE received signal to terminate VPN connection

31     14:39:52.328  09/23/09  Sev=Info/6   IPSEC/0x63700023
TCP RST sent to RemotePeerIP, src port 1942, dst port 10000

32     14:39:52.328  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IPSEC/0x63700014
Deleted all keys

33     14:39:52.328  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IPSEC/0x63700014
Deleted all keys

34     14:39:52.328  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IPSEC/0x63700014
Deleted all keys

35     14:39:52.328  09/23/09  Sev=Info/4   IPSEC/0x6370000A
IPSec driver successfully stopped

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you seeing any drops in your firewall log the corresponds to the time that this connection drops?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the firewall log on our end that indicates a problem.

Comment: we have the same issue with my employer. and worse, the vpn will drop and not reconnect automatically! what we are doing now is testing a few units with openvpn, which has been a much better experience thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't much about explaining why, but I and (IT Helpdesk of the company) have found 4.x version much better what comes to Cisco VPN disconnections (especially if you use F-Secure firewall). So we always recommend people to change to older version. If someone knows the real reason why and how to configure the firewall with 5.x version, would like to hear the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall logs, and also it's resource usage, it it's overloaded it won't be able to route traffic. Causing the timeouts your are experiencing. Also check the interface stats on the firewall and switches that connect you to firewall/internet. If you loosing packets because of bad cable, you'll have problems.

This really does look the firewall is closing ports, look for timeout setting on the firewall.